# Accessing Data Nested in Dictionary in Array in Dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm feeling stumped and looking for help. I'm trying to access data that lives inside of a dictionary that's inside of an array that is inside of a dictionary. See below:

```
{
    'files': [
        {
            'type': 'diskDescriptor', 
            'name': '[VM] VM1/VM1.vmdk',
            'key': 4, 
            'size': 0
        }, 
        {
            'type': 'diskExtent', 
            'name': '[VM] VM1/VM1-flat.vmdk', 
            'key': 5, 
            'size': 32457621504
        }
    ], 
    'capacity': 32505856, 
    'label': 'Hard disk 1', 
    'descriptor': '[VM] VM1/VM1.vmdk',
    'committed': 31696896, 
    'device': {
        'summary': '32,505,856 KB', 
        '_obj': <pysphere.vi_property.VIProperty object at 0x17442910>, 
        'unitNumber': 0, 
        'key': 2000, 
        'label': 'Hard disk 1', 
        'type': 'VirtualDisk',
        'capacityInKB': 32505856
    }
}
```

If I want to access, let's say the descriptor key value how would I go about this with Python? For some reason all of the combinations I've tried do not work.

Any help and guidance would be appreciated and if more information is needed I can provide. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets call your main dictionary bob, because I like bob:

```
bob['files'] #get you the list with second dictionary

bob['files'][0] #get you the first item in the list, which is the nested 2nd dictionary

bob['files'][0]['type'] == 'diskDescriptor'
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the prompt response. But what if I want to get 'capacityInKB' or 'label' (located under 'device')? Since it's not in an array I can't get it with using [] and the specified item. For example -  bob['files'][2]['label'] or bob['files'][3]['capacityInKB']...

Comment: Nevermind - I figured my additional question out. Thanks again!

Comment: You can always try these out in ipython to make the debugging process so much easier, if thats an option for you. Just print them out one step at a time, and it will quickly all start to make sense.